# parametrize the server name in nginx conf

Tags: nginx

I have multiple domains all pointing to the same VM. (mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com, mydomain3.eu)
Now I have a huge nginx.conf which looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name   *.mydomain1.com;
    ssl  on;
    ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain1.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain1.com.key;
    # hundred more lines of rules
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name   *.mydomain2.com;
    ssl  on;
    ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain2.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain2.com.key;
    # the same hundred more lines of rules
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name   *.mydomain3.eu;
    ssl  on;
    ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain3.eu.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain3.eu.key;
    # the same hundred more lines of rules
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this - because currently I'm cloning such a huge code blcok when I have to add a new domain and only change the 3 lines where my domain name differs. I thought about some kind of parametrization, like (without knowing the correct syntax):

```
SERVER_NAME = {request_server_name}
ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/${SERVER_NAME}.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/${SERVER_NAME}.key;
```

is this possible? How?

Comment: Common blocks of code should be placed into a separate file and imported using the `include` directive.

Comment: @RichardSmith, please post your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do about it

**Multi Domain SAN Certificate**

You can purchase a multi domain SAN certificate. Which allows your to use different domains in the same certificate. So this way you wont have to have multiple blocks. In case you are using a self-signed certificate you can still create SAN certificate yourself

**Use OpenRestry or Nginx+LUA**

You can use OpenResty or Nginx with LUA support and use the [`ssl_certificate_by_lua_block`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block) directive of he same.

> syntax: ssl_certificate_by_lua_block { lua-script }
>
> context: server
>
> phase: right-before-SSL-handshake
>
> This directive runs user Lua code when NGINX is about to start the SSL handshake for the downstream SSL (https) connections.
>
> It is particularly useful for setting the SSL certificate chain and the corresponding private key on a per-request basis. It is also useful to load such handshake configurations nonblockingly from the remote (for example, with the cosocket API). And one can also do per-request OCSP stapling handling in pure Lua here as well.

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block

Also see below articles for some example implementations

https://medium.com/@mtourne/how-to-use-nginx-for-ssl-termination-for-any-domain-dc2e2c630058

https://blog.readme.io/auto-generating-ssl-certificates-for-custom-domains-using-lets-encrypt/

Comment: Sounds good, but I'd prefer nginx only. So the `include` directive mentioned by Richard was a good alternative.

Comment: So you creating multiple file for each section?

Comment: No, creating *one* file containing these "hundred more lines of rules" and included this file in each server{} section.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. I was trying to solve a different issue related to certs and ddin't realize it was common rules that was the main issue. Yes include would be the best option then. I will keep this answer as information only here. Though it is not a relevant solution to your problem